# How to trim trailing 0 ASCII characters from a string in MS SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, string, ascii

I have a string of type `VARCHAR(128)` in MS SQL Server, which has this value: 'abc       '.

However, these trailing "spaces" are not regular spaces (ASCII 32), they are of ASCII 0. I want to trim these trailing "spaces", but I could not get it to work.

I have tried the following approaches:

`ltrim` and `rtrim`

```
replace('abc       ', CHAR(0), '')

substring('abc       ', 0, charindex(CHAR(0), 'abc       '))
```

But none of these seem to work as intended.

How can I remove these trailing ASCII 0 characters from the string?

Comment: I believe a CHAR(0) is a NULL value. Have you tried CHAR(32)?
Or convert to NVARCHAR(128) and then ltrim(rtrim('abc       '))

Comment: `REPLACE` should work according to this script: `DECLARE @a varchar(10) = CAST(0x616200 AS varchar(10));
SELECT DATALENGTH(@a) AS before, DATALENGTH(REPLACE(@a, CHAR(0), '')) AS after;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried your code and there was no replacement so I check the ASCII code of your space and it was 32, not 0:

```
select replace('abc       ', CHAR(32), '') + '*', ascii(right('abc       ', 1))
```

Here I make for you your test data
and replace char(0) using old sql server collation:

```
declare @t table (c varchar(128)  collate latin1_general_ci_as);
insert into @t values ('abc' + replicate(char(0),10));

select c, len(replace(c, char(0), '')) as len_not_replaced,
       replace(c collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS, char(0), '')  + '*' as correct_replacement
from @t;
```

Comment: Yes, StackOverflow does not let me paste 0 ASCII characters into the textfield so I had to use regular spaces.

Comment: Ok, in this case the question is duplicate and the answer is given already. I've just checked ascii just in case and wrote here what I've seen

Comment: @sfandler I think a little and update my answer in case you still have your question uncleared

Comment: That solves my problem. I already found the same solution somewhere else but thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

LTRIM and RTRIM only remove spaces, not any whitespace character. If you are certain they are char(0) simply use replace.

```
declare @Something varchar(20) = 'abc' + replicate(char(0), 5) + 'def'

select replace(@Something, char(0), '')
```

Comment: Simple `REPLACE` for `CHAR(0)` may not work, it depends on the column collation, as shown in the duplicate question. It will work if `varchar` is cast to `varbinary` first, or the collation is changed to a more suitable.